# shouldOverrideUrlLoading() never gets called

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

The shouldOverrideUrlLoading() never gets called if I click a link within the webview.
(It doesn't show the toast or logs anything). I've tried also onPageFinished and it doesn't get called too. I read other posts where users are having problems that this is not called only sometimes, but in my case it's completely ignored.

```
    webview = new WebView(MyActivity.this);

    webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
    webview.loadData(Html.getHtml(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
    webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean  shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            new M("shouldOverrideUrlLoading",getApplicationContext());
            Log.v("ESSE3", "shouldOverrideUrlLoading()");

            System.out.println(url);

            System.out.println(Html.getHtml());
            webview.loadData(Html.getHtml(), "text/html", "UTF-8");
                            return true;

        }
    });
    webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    setContentView(webview);
```

Tried with/without javascript enabled or returning true or false within the method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You call `setWebViewClient()` twice. Once with your overriding method and once with an empty `WebViewClient`! That's why your method isn't getting called.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

    @Override
    public boolean  shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        ....
    }
});
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```